# How to nest table withing table read from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I got this json object which its structure similar to this:

```
vendor have name, phone, fax, contacts
contacts have firstName, lastName, title, phone, email
```

I have created the first level in the table, but i didn't how to create the second nested level

```
function getData(vType) {
                $.getJSON('/LocalApp/VendorController', {
                    vendorType : vType,
                    time : "2pm"
                }, function(vendorsJson) {
                    $('#vendors').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();

                    var vendorTable = $('#vendors');

                    $.each(vendorsJson, function(index, vendor) {
                        $('<tr>').appendTo(vendorTable).append(
                                $('<td>').text(vendor.name)).append(
                                $('<td>').text(vendor.phone)).append(
                                $('<td>').text(vendor.fax)).append(
                                '<table class="contactTable"><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Phone</th><th>E-Mail</th></tr></table>');

                    });
                });
            }
```

So how can i add vendor.contacts as a nested table in jQuery code?
i know my code is not clean, jquery is confusing to me compared to Java

Comment: It's not at all clear what you have for input or what you want for output.  Can you clarify?

Comment: have nested json object need to view it as a table, last column of the first table has a nested table. vendor have: name, phone, fax, contacts*
contacts have: firstName, lastName, title, phone, email

Comment: Oh, then it's easy.  Just write some code.

Comment: can you tell me how to use for(var x; x<josn.lenght;x++) to navigate a nested josn object.

Comment: you already have `$.each(vendorsJson...` and in there are accessing `vendor`, seems to me you could `$.each(vendor.contacts...`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want the table in a cell of the vendor or not, but try something like this...

```
var contactTableHtml = '<table class="contactTable"><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Title</th><th>Phone</th><th>E-Mail</th></tr></table>';

var vendorTableContent = $.map(vendorsJson,function (index, vendor) {

    var contactTableContentHtml = $.map(vendor.contacts,function (index, contact) {
        return "<tr><td>" + contact.firstName + "</td><td>" + contact.lastName + "</td><td>" + contact.title + "</td><td>" + contact.phone + "</td><td>" + contact.email + "</td></tr>";
    }).join("");

    return '<tr>' +
        '<td>' + vendor.name + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + vendor.phone + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + vendor.fax + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + contactTableHtml + contactTableContentHtml + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';

}).join("");

vendorTable.append(vendorTableContent);
```

First I create a subtable as a string and then add it to the main table. I also suggest to create one big html string and add it once to the DOM. This is a lot quicker then calling $('...') everytime.

**PS.** Haven't been able to test it, but let me know if you get an error.

Comment: @Skystar3 Happy with my answer? Would you like to approve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're very constrained for how much you can send with the page (that is, every single K of data counts against you), I don't think jQuery is a good fit for this kind of thing.

I think of JSON + something => HTML as templating, so I usually use a JavaScript templating tool like [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) to do that kind of thing. It's a more natural fit. Plus you can try right now with a site like [Try Handlebars.js](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/) to interactively craft a template that takes some of your sample JSON and output the HTML you desire.

In all likelihood, a {{#each}} with another {{#each}} inside of it could probably handle the conversion of a nested JSON to whatever HTML you're after.

Comment: P.S. I'm not saying jQuery isn't great, I use it too. I just prefer to use Handlebars for templates and jQuery for what it does well. For an extra 30K, Handlebars is something I use several times on my pages to make templates easy.